# How to allow "+" character in email validation?

Tags: regex, validation

We're using the validate.js plugin for form validation. I want to allow "+" in the email field so I can use multiple test accounts with Gmail. However, the plugin validation doesn't allow it.

I'm not very good with regex, how would I alter the below to allow the + character? (I tried going to that commented URL but the page no longer exists it seems.)

```
    email: function( value, element ) {
        // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
        return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value);
    },
```

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)! Btw, why not ask Scott?

Comment: Holy shlemolee, that's quite the regex you've got there.

Comment: That expression is like a Rube Goldberg machine.

Answer (score 2):

That is a terribly written regular expression. Not only is it far too long and complicated, but for some reason the author decided it was a good idea to escape characters in a `[...]` character class, which you absolutely should not do.

Instead, try this Regex, from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (these guys know their Regex).

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i
```

I also agree with [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s comment - don't validate e-mail addresses using complex Regex. Even the one I suggest is overkill for most of today's applications.

Comment: From the above that you posted, how would I allow the + character? Or does yours already allow it? I'm hopeless with regex.

Comment: I'll refrain from downvoting, but honestly Bergi's comment is by far the most sensible answer for this. Even this expression is way to complicated.